# AndEngine - Enable a disabled child button based on whether the parent button has been pressed

Tags: java, android, andengine

With the current set-up that I have thanks to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116158/andengine-drawing-a-line-between-level-objects-entites-using-matching-ids). How do I disabled child button based on whether the parent button has been pressed? for example Button2 is currently disabled, but when I press Button1 I can now press Button2 and if I press Button2, Button3 and Button4 become enabled and can now be pressed. 
So far the way I'm doing it is as following:
Declare a boolean:

```
boolean Enable = false;
```

Change Enable from false to true when a button is clicked:

```
if (type.equals(TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_GAMEBUTTON1)) {
levelObject = new ButtonSprite(x, y, resourcesManager.gamebutton1_region, resourcesManager.gamebuttonpressed_region, vbom, new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {                           
        Enable = true;
    }
});
```

}

Disable all other button except for the first one, and seeing as Enable is still false before a button is pressed the other buttons should be disabled:

```
if (ButtonSpriteID != 1) {
levelObject.setEnabled(Enable);
levelObject.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

}

And then final if the id of the child matches the child_id of the parent, the button should be enabled when a button is pressed because Enable should then be set to true:

```
for (int k = 0; k < ButtonSpriteChild.length; k++){
if (ButtonSpriteChild[k] == ButtonSpriteID){
    levelObject.setEnabled(Enable);
    levelObject.setColor(Color.WHITE);
}                               
}
```

I get not errors when running the code, but none of it seems to work as I intended it to. So any help would be great.

---

### Update 1: So I've tried and removed Enable boolean and tried this:

```
if (ButtonSpriteID != 1) {
levelObject.setEnabled(false);
levelObject.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

levelObject.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
    for (int k = 0; k < ButtonSpriteChild.length; k++){
        if (ButtonSpriteChild[k] == ButtonSpriteID){
            levelObject.setEnabled(true);
            levelObject.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }                               
    }
}
});
```

Still doesn't work. It was suggest that I override onTouchedArea but I'm not sure how I would implement that.

---

### Update 2: I've now tried:

```
if (levelObjects.get(j).isPressed()) {
    levelObjects.get(i).setEnabled(true);
    levelObjects.get(i).setColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Still doesn't work. Still looking for help.

---

### Update 3: I've now tried:

```
for (final ButtonSprite buttonSprite : levelObjects) {
    if (ButtonSpriteID != 1) {
        buttonSprite.setEnabled(false);
        buttonSprite.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    buttonSprite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX,
        float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            for (int k = 0; k < ButtonSpriteChild.length; k++){

                if (ButtonSpriteChild[k] == ButtonSpriteID){
                    buttonSprite.setEnabled(true);
                    buttonSprite.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }   
        }
    });
}
```

Still not working, any help? Please?

---

### Update 4: I've now tried:

```
levelObjects.get(j).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX,
    float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
        for (int k = 0; k < ButtonSpriteChild.length; k++){

            if (ButtonSpriteChild[k] == ButtonSpriteID){
                levelObjects.get(i).setEnabled(true);
                levelObjects.get(i).setColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

That does not work as its giving me errors about setting "i" to final, but can't do that as "i" is in a for loop.

---

### Update 5: So I've tried

```
if (ButtonSpriteChild[k] == ButtonSpriteID){
    levelObject.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX,
                float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            levelObject.setEnabled(true);
            levelObject.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        }
    });
}
```

Still doesn't work.

---

### Update 6: So I've tried

```
if (ButtonSpriteChild[k] == ButtonSpriteID){
    levelObject.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX,
            float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            levelObject.setEnabled(true);
            levelObject.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    });
}
```

Something weird happens only one button/levelobject is effected if press another button and some of the buttons that I press are not children or parent of that button.

Comment: It was suggest that I override onTouchedArea but I'm not sure how I would implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During your XML parsing when you are creating the buttons, we will take the opportunity to enable only GAMEBUTTON1, disable all of the others and call a function to enable all children when the button is pressed. I.e.,

```
if (type.equals(TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_GAMEBUTTON1))
{
    final ButtonSprite levelObject = new ButtonSprite(x, y, resourcesManager.gamebutton1_region, vbom, new  OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) 
        {       
            //This button sprite has been clicked so lets enable any child sprites

            EnableChildButtons(this); //See sub routine later

        }
     });
     //For game button 1, we will enable it,
     levelObject.setEnabled(true);
     levelObject.setColor(Color.WHITE);
     //Hereafter for further buttons, although the rest of the code will be the same
     //will be disabled after creation with the following two lines in place of the latter
     // levelObject.setEnabled(false);
     // levelObject.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}
//...(rest of your code in previous post)
```

Before the sub routine EnableChildButtons, I made an ammendment to your levelObjectUserData, I replaced your int array of child IDs,

```
public int[] ChildID = {-1};
```

With a List,

```
public List<Integer> ChildIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

When calling the code which stores your child IDs simply use the following with your code,

```
for (int i = 0;i<childString_id.length;i++)
{
    MyData.ChildIDs.add(Integer.parseInt(childString_id[i]));
}
```

We then just need to write the function to enable the children,

```
private void EnableChildButtons(final ButtonSprite mButtonSprite)
{
    //To cut down on syntax length get a pointer to the button user data
    final levelObjectUserData mUserData = ((levelObjectUserData) (mButtonSprite.getUserData()));

    //We will be careful and run this on the update so we do not alter states
    //while they are currently being processed by the update thread!
    mActivity.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            //Go through all of the buttons child ids
            for (int i = 0;i<mUserData.ChildIDs.size();i++)
            {

                //Locate the button with that ID as will be refernced in our levelObjects
                //linked list
                for (int j = 0;j<levelObjects.size();j++)
                {
                    final int ButtonSpriteID = ((levelObjectUserData) (levelObjects.get(j).getUserData())).ID;

                    if (mUserData.ChildIDs.get(i) == ButtonSpriteID)
                    {
                        //We have found a child button, so enable it!
                        ((ButtonSprite) levelObjects.get(j)).setEnabled(true);
                        ((ButtonSprite) levelObjects.get(j)).setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

     });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, Just as an idea for improvement you could think about replacing your list of ChildIDs ints with a list of pointers to the child button sprite instances themselves. This would mean you could for go the nested loop searching through levelObjects for the children every time you wish to locate them and get to them directly, speeding things up a little.

Comment: Something weird is now happing when drawing the lines from the previous question when I changed the ChildID from an a array to a list, some lines are not being drawn and the ones that are, are not been drawn correctly